# Domain for one2many not working Odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

In my module I want to filter one2many records based on current date. 
This is my xml code

```xml
<field name="record_ids" domain="[('end_date', '&gt;', cur_date)]">
    <tree string="records_tree">
        <field name="record_id"/>
        <field name="record"/>
        <field name="start_date"/>
        <field name="end_date"/>
    </tree>
</field>
```

cur_date is a functional field I added to get current date.

My problem is records are not filtered in the view. Also it doesn't show any error message

Answer (score 7):

you are define the domain in the XML file .
so this domain it's not work .

please define in the .py file .

**For Example :**

**'record_ids':fields.one2many('model_name','model_id','Record',domain=[('end_date', '>=', 'cur_date')])**

here the cur_date you need to define  one function  field which show the current date.

So Please check this may be it's help full to you :).

Answer (score 3):

I also faced this problem, and the solution is put domain in **.py** file, in **.xml** domain is not working properly.

```
import_transaction_log_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name = 'transaction.log','sale_order_id', string = 'Import Transaction Log',domain=[('operation_type','=','import')])
```

in example `operation_type` field is in `transaction.log` model.

Answer (score 1):

Write domain in end_date field, like this:

```xml
 <field name="record_ids" >
 <tree string="records_tree">
    <field name="record_id"/>
    <field name="record"/>
    <field name="start_date"/>
    <field name="end_date" domain="[('end_date', '&gt;', cur_date)]"/>
</tree>
</field>
```

i think it will help you..

Answer (score 0):

domain contains 'field name' 'expression' 'value'.
instead of value you given a field

```xml
 <field name="record_ids" domain="[('field', 'expression', value)]">
```

Comment: thanks. can you suggest a method to provide current date as the value?

Comment: i dont know it works...   make a date field in your model and then call that field in your domain filter as 'model rec.date_field_name'..u will get the date in that field

Comment: @Abdulwahid they  want the solution of that Query(Question) not the syntax of domain,how to apply domain in one2many fields.

Comment: okey no issue but try to understand the proper question and then after you should apply for your answer

Comment: If your answer may not sure or not correct then just make comment on that question nothing else

Answer (score 0):

you can pass only those field in domain those are store in Database.
So in that case cur_date is not store in Database.
Then also you need to pass into domain so you need to store cur_date field from py.

Answer (score 0):

first of all, one2many fields are not for selection purpose. We can create the new records or update the existing records in one2many field. so we cannot apply domain to a one2many field.
eg: sale_order_line field in sale.order

moreover one2many fields, functional_fields [**if store=True not specified ] wont store in the table.

Many2one or Many2Many are used for selecting the records [ as well as creating new ones ], so here we can apply domain and we can restrict the user to select some type of records

eg: Many2one- product_id field in sale.order.line 
many2many - user_ids field in res.users

So, in order to get your task, try many2many and apply domain, then the records will be filtered

Answer (score 0):

Add it in python:
Eg:

```
xn_cutting_ids = fields.One2many('mrp.bom.line', 'bom_id', 'Cutting Lines', domain=lambda self:[('xn_stage','=','cut')])
```

Use `domain = lambda` else there is a chance of error while using string values in domain.

Here `xn_stage` is in `mrp.bom.line` model.

Answer (score 0):

On Odoo V11

Define a function that returns a domain in the one2many field definition.

```
class GroupContract(models.Model):
_name = 'group.contract'

@api.multi
def _domain_move_ids(self):
    """Odoo default domain for many2one field is [('contract_id', '=', self.id)].
    This function adds new criteria according to your needs"""
    res = []
    if len(self) == 1: # do not compute in tree view
        ids = self.env['stock.move'].search([
            ('state', '=', 'done'),
            ('date', '>=', self.start_date),
            ('date', '<=', self.end_date)
        ]).ids # choose your own criteria
        res = [('id', 'in', ids)]
    return res

start_date = fields.Date(string="Start date", required=True)
end_date = fields.Date(string="End date", required=True)
move_ids = fields.One2many(comodel_name='stock.move', inverse_name='contract_id', string="Moves",
                           domain=lambda self: self._domain_move_ids())
```